# Sort based on function

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a method that given 2 strings he returns a number (between 0 and 100) which represents is how alike they are, being 0 "not similar at all" and 100 "they are the same"

Now the thing is that i have a list of County (string name, GeoRef coordinates, string Mayor) which i would like to sort based on the return of my function...
im looking for something like `myList.Sort(f=>MyScoreEvaluator("York",f.Name))`

Can anyone tell me how to do so?

**Edit1:** I dont think that the method "Sort" is quite i want... Sort compare itens inside of the list... i want to compare the itens of the list against a external info and based on that result sort the items

The OrderBy and OrderByDescending are returning the same item order...

**Edit2:** Heres is the code of the OrderBy I'm using: `aux.OrderBy(f => StringComparisonHelper.HowAlike(f.Name, countyNameSearched));`

Comment: Did you try `OrderBy`?

Comment: Yes... did not work... Ascending or descending returns the same result...

Comment: You need to re-assign your List, something like: `list = list.OrderBy(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name))`

Comment: @CuongLe Correct! my initial ideia was actually working... all i was missing was the reassign... post as answer so i can accept it pls!

Comment: @CuongLe Exactly. Remember `.ToList()` after `.OrderBy` if he wants to reassign. This changes only this variable. The old `List<>` instance remains unchanged (in case others refer it). For actually sorting the _same_ `List<>` instance, do use `Sort` (as in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534966.aspx), and re-assign your list:

```
list = list.OrderBy(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `OrderBy` in LINQ:

```
var sorted = myList.OrderBy(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name))
```

Or to sort descendingly:

```
var sortedDesc = myList.OrderByDescending(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name))
```

Comment: i edited and post the code of the order by... it's quite what youre using

Comment: @Leonardo That's because `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` don't sort or change the source they operate on. You need to pickup the return value somehow. You can call `.ToList()` on it to get a ***new*** `List<>`. Then you might want to assign to `myList` variable. The old `List<>` object remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
list.OrderBy(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name))
```

Or Implement a custom Comparer:

```
public static int SortByName(County x, County y)
{
    return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
}
```

Usage:

```
list.Sort(new Comparison<County>(SortByName))
```

Comment: The last example seems to only work if he has a `List<string>`. But he hasn't.

Comment: In which case you could substitute the `string` for whatever type it is you're comparing, by the looks of things it's a `County`. I will edit.

Comment: After your edit, you simply sort alphabetically by name. Nowhere do you mention if the "score evaluater" finds the distance to `"York"` long og short.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy to use the LINQ `OrderBy` extension (see others' answers).

If you want to use `Sort`, it would be:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => MyScoreEvaluator("York", x.Name)
    .CompareTo(MyScoreEvaluator("York", y.Name)));
```

This assumes that `myList` is a `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`.

If you want the other sort direction, swap `x` and `y` on one side of the lambda arrow `=>`, of course.

EDIT:

Remember `.Sort` method on `List<>` *modifies* the same instance. The return type of `Sort` method is `void`. On the other hand, `OrderBy` creates a new `IEnumerable<>` on which you can call `.ToList()` to get a *new* list object. The old object is unchanged. You might assign the new object to the variable that held the original list. *Other* variables that reference the old object won't be affected by that. Example:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(f => MyScoreEvaluator("York", f.Name)).ToList();
```

NEW EDIT:

If performance is an issue, it's not clear which of these two to use. The `OrderBy` method calls the `MyScoreEvaluator` only once per item in your original list. The `Sort` method as presented here, calls `MyScoreEvaluator` a lot more times, because it doesn't "remember" the result of each `MyScoreEvaluator` call (the `Comparison<>` delegate instance is a black box to the `Sort` algorithm). So if it wants to compare `"Fork"` and `"Kork"`, it calls `MyScoreEvaluator` twice. Then afterwards if it wants to compare `"Kork"` and `"Yorc"`, it does the `"Kork"` `MyScoreEvaluator` again. On the other hand, the sort algorithm of `List<>.Sort` is superior to that of `OrderBy`.

Comment: I wonder why two people downvoted me. I included a "New Edit". Maybe that addresses what they dislike about my answer?